# What does random.seed([list of int]) do?

Tags: python

I know what random.seed(int) does, like below:

```
random.seed(10)
```

But I saw a code which uses random.seed([list of int]), like below:

```
random.seed([1, 2, 1000])
```

What is the difference between passing a list and int to random.seed ?

Comment: The docs specify the behave for `int`, `str`, `bytes` and `bytearray`, but they don't seem to say anything about `list`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed Your best bet is probably to just look at the implementation and try to see what it does.

Comment: I get "unhashable type `list`" when I try to set a random seed to a list, which suggests to me that it's trying to hash the argument (and failing, in the case of lists) in order to get an integer seed.

Comment: If you found code that does that, they must have modified the way `random.seed` performs, or perhaps imported a different library `as random`, because the standard `seed()` function does not support that argument, as @silviomayolo correctly points out.

Comment: The code you got this from may be using numpys random (imported as `from numpy import random`). As others have pointed out this does not work with pythons regular random. In that case refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is basically in the comments, but putting it together: it appears the code you found imports `random` from `numpy`, instead of importing the standard Python `random` module:

```
from numpy import random

random.seed([1, 2, 1000])
```

Not recommended, to avoid exactly the confusion you're running into.

`numpy` can use a 1d array of integers as a seed (presumably because it uses a different pseudo-random function than Python itself to generate 'random' numbers, which can use a more complex seed), as described in [the documentation for numpy.RandomState](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState)

Comment: Yeah, this would never pass muster if I was the code reviewer. That module should always be referred to as `np.random`.